# Wordpress creates plugin tables locally, not in production

Tags: wordpress

I am making a plugin for a client and i am trying to install it on their test server.

When i install the plugin locally, everything works fine. However, when i install it on their test server, the tables are not created. They don't have debug turned on, and i don't get any message that there was an error installing. I verify that the tables are not created, by using a plugin called database browser.

Here is the code, that creates the table, everything else is cut out. With this code the tables are created locally:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Integration Rating
*/

class IntegrationRating {

    const INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME = "ir_integrations";
    const RATINGS_TABLE_NAME = "ir_ratings";

    /**
     * Called when the plugin is activated. Creates the tables for the plugin.
     */
    public static function activate_plugin() {

        global $wpdb;

        $sqlCreateTable1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME . "` (
            `post_id` bigint(40) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `num_raters` int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
            CONSTRAINT `post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

        $sqlCreateTable2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::RATINGS_TABLE_NAME . "` (
            `post_id` bigint(40) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `rater_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `rating` int(1) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`rater_email`),
            CONSTRAINT `ratings_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME . "` (`post_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

        $wpdb->query($sqlCreateTable1);
        $wpdb->query($sqlCreateTable2);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the plugin is uninstalled. Removes the plugins tables from the database.
     */
    public static function uninstall_plugin() {

        global $wpdb;

        $sqlDropTable1 = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME;
        $sqlDropTable2 = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::RATINGS_TABLE_NAME;

        // Delete ratings first because of constraints
        $wpdb->query($sqlDropTable2);
        $wpdb->query($sqlDropTable1);
    }

}

function ir_activate_plugin() {
    IntegrationRating::activate_plugin();
}

function ir_uninstall_plugin() {
    IntegrationRating::uninstall_plugin();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ir_activate_plugin');
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'ir_uninstall_plugin');

new IntegrationRating();
```

I'm hoping someone has some clues to what could be wrong.

Comment: Guesswork, probably, the database user you are using doesn't have enough permissions to alter database schema.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same error but my client turned on debug log.

And the problem is `REFERENCES` isn't granted for current user.

Grant `REFERENCES` privilege then reinstall the plugin could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your mysql 
ENGINE=InnoDB to ENGINE=MyISAM

When you want to show debugging and find what is actual problem when creating a table and your plugin is already activated. First enable in debug in your function activate_plugin after $wpdb global declare. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors

```
public static function activate_plugin() {

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        ........
```

After make a new function using wordpress hook **init**.

```
add_action( 'init', 'plugin_table_installed' ); // Debugging complete remove this

function plugin_table_installed(){
   IntegrationRating::activate_plugin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace below functions after check ?

```
public static function activate_plugin() {

        global $wpdb;

        $sqlCreateTable1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME . "` (
            `post_id` bigint(40) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `num_raters` int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
            CONSTRAINT `post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

        $sqlCreateTable2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::RATINGS_TABLE_NAME . "` (
            `post_id` bigint(40) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `rater_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `rating` int(1) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`rater_email`),
            CONSTRAINT `ratings_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `" . $wpdb->prefix . IntegrationRating::INTEGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME . "` (`post_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sqlCreateTable1);
        dbDelta($sqlCreateTable2);
    }
```